# Why are some of android.os classes full of errors when opened in the editor?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, declaration, android-sdk-2.3

When I look at classes like AsyncTask or SQLiteDatabase or a lot of the classes in the android package (such as android.os) by selecting GoTo>Declaration, I see that there is a large number of "cannot resolve" or "cannot access" errors. Why do I see these errors when obviously, no errors exist and Android can easily use them?

[image: Example, when opening AsyncTask]

Comment: Please provide a concrete example.

Comment: Maybe you have an issue in your xml and your R.java file is not created.

Comment: Added screenshot. Kristy I am talking about Android's classes which has nothing to with xml or my project. Think of classes that are defined for Android and we use to write our projects

Comment: Did you try cleaning and rebuilding the project?

Comment: No, I never downloaded the source code. If what I see in the screenshot is not the source code then what is it? They are part of the Android SDK.

Comment: Once again, my question has nothing to do with a specific project. I am referring to the classes that are defined in the Android SDK

Comment: Also, I have never had any problems in the one year that I have been developing apps. I do not have any problems now either. But when I look at the classes in Android SDK I see warnings and errors everywhere which tells me that those function are not meant for me or Android Studio to see and might be for another purpose or compiled on a different level

Comment: Can you compile your project?

Comment: Yes, I have developed several apps and never have I had any problems. I noticed this since day 1. But back then I didn't know anything about Android and now I am curious to learn how android works underneath

Comment: When you hover at the warning you get a message. Can you please post the exact message?

Comment: "cannot access android.os.AsynkTask.WorkerRunnable" or another case for annotations such as "@WorkerThread" I see "cannot resolve symbol WorkerThread".

Comment: Do you have the SDK/Java versions set for your project/module?

Comment: I've worked with 21 through 23 and all are similar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is due to the fact that the SDK only includes the high level interfaces and not the actual implementations. To resolve this, you should download the AOSP source and change the source from SDK to the relevant source code location.